# Debugging Delphi programs with GDB

Tags: delphi, msbuild, gdb, visual-studio-code, rsm

My goal is to use VS Code for developing Delphi application and I can already build Delphi projects (.dproj) and group projects (.groupproj) with debug information. But I use RAD Studio\9.0 for compilation and it puts symbols inside .rsm files and I am not sure, if GDB can debug executable using those files, because by default it tells me that "no debugging symbols found" even when it sees the .rsm files.

Is there a way to make GDB use the .rsm files or a way in MSBuild to let Delphi create some symbol format usable by GDB for debugging?

Comment: Not easily. You'll need to do the heavy lifting yourself.

Comment: In that case I prolly convert .dproj to .lpi and use FPC, which creates symbol format compatible with GDB :(

Comment: I know it's already 4 years old, but did you succeed in using VS Code for Delphi? I have the same challenge here :-)